# Reference to AppCompatActivity object created via startActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent, android-activity, android-context

I have got approximately this Activity construct:

`MainActivity` starts `Activity2` startsForResult `Activity3`

Now I want to have the Activity result of `Activity3` being send to the `MainActivity`.
But to create the Intent, I need to have a reference to the `MainActivity`.

I tried:

- getting the reference from the intent from `MainActivity` to `Activity2` (no method for that)
- reusing the intent from `MainActivity` to `Activity2` and changing the target to `Activity3` (complicated and dirty)
- making a public static reference to the `MainActivity` (memory leak warning)

Comment: Use the fragments in place of Activities. If you do so you will have lots of options like "LiveData"

Comment: If you expect `MainActivity` to receive a result, why aren't you starting `Activity2` with `startActivityForResult()`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Thank you, I didn't think about that.

Comment: @VikashParajuli Thanks, I am going to take a look at those!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity

```
goToNextActivity(){
    startActivityForResult(intentActivity2, SOME_REQUEST_CODE);
}

onActivityForResult(...){
    doSomeStuffWithResult();
}
```

In your Activity2

```
goToNextActivity(){
    intentActivityC = new Intent(...);
    intentActivityC.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT);
    startActivity(intentActivityC);
}
```

do not forget to use `FLAG_ACTIVITY_FORWARD_RESULT` in Activity2

In your Activity3

```
goBackToActivityA(){
    setResult(someResultCode); //setResult send the data
    finish();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the result being passed through was what I was looking for!